# Mod deflate: Server taking more resources after enabling compression in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, compression, gzip, httpd.conf, deflate

I have added following snippet in httpd.conf

```
 # mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Restrict compression to these MIME types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

# Level of compression (Highest 9 - Lowest 1)
DeflateCompressionLevel 1

# Netscape 4.x has some problems.
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

</IfModule>
```

Compression is working absolutely fine, but the server is taking too long to respond back to the requests, I have checked with `top`  command as well, which shows 99% cpu usage.
How can I make this compression more efficient? or any other commands that may come handy in analyzing further?

Answer (score 0):

If the responses are cacheable, add mod_expires and mod_cache+mod_disk_cache to dynamically cache the compressed variants.